# How can I get a populated combobox to display its options in Swift?

Tags: cocoa, swift, nscombobox

With this code I'm able to populate the items in an `NSComboBox`, but the combobox itself is always empty when you expand it in the app.

The number of items being logged is accurate. I know this is rather basic, but I've read and re-read the docs at developer.apple.com and have looked for examples of comboboxes in Swift to no avail, which is quite surprising to me.

```
@IBOutlet var someComboBox: NSComboBox!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    someComboBox = NSComboBox()
    someComboBox.addItemWithObjectValue("Foo")
    someComboBox.addItemWithObjectValue("Bar")
    someComboBox.addItemWithObjectValue("Baz")
    println(someComboBox.numberOfItems)
}
```

and the result:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comboBox is an `IBOutlet`, so the object is created for you already by the Storyboard; you just need to initialize it.  So remove:

```
someComboBox = NSComboBox()
```

because that is allocating a new combo box and overwriting the reference to the one created in the Storyboard.  Your new comboBox is not the one that is on screen.

Comment: If I could give you more than one upvote I would. Thanks friend.