# simple dropdown box in swift

Tags: swift, drop-down-menu

Which control to use to have a simple dropdown box in swift ?

I managed to use the UIPickerview, but this is not usable in my case.
The UIPickerview shows the values before and after and will overlap texts and titles in my gui. I also don't like to waste space in my gui only to have these sexy controls.

Is there a standard control for me, or do I have really to implement my own control ?

Comment: Probably NSCombobox, which I just found ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114909/how-can-i-get-a-populated-combobox-to-display-its-options-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know apple does not provide standard control for Drop down menu.

There can be a workaround using UIPopoverController. You can use UIPopoverController's following initializer:

```
init(contentViewController viewController: UIViewController)
```

And pass the listViewController you want to show in the contentViewController.

Note: It will show the items as a Popover and not a DropDown. So if you want to implement a Dropdown you will have to make it on your own.

Comment: Thanks for helping. isn't this awkward that apple doesn't offer a simple dropdown box, which everyone is familiar since years !

Comment: Yeah it's awkward. They should probably provide a standard control.